# Using 'Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy' permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Assuming there are two registered apps A & B.

I want to use Microsoft Graph API permission: "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy" on App A to be able manage App B client secrets. I didn't find an option to set on App B the ownership of App A. Under home -> App Registrations -> 'App A' -> Owners, I'm able to add just user principals, not application principals.

Am I missing something here? How can I set the ownership?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. You can use the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), to add an application as an [owner to the app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request) with the API, since the Azure UI only supports adding users.

The request should be a `POST` to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}/owners/$ref`, where the `id` is the Object ID of the App Registration (App B).

The body should be

```json
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{ownerId}"
}
```

Where the `ownerId` is the Object ID from the Enterprise Application (App A) that should own the App Registration (App B).

Answer (score 0):

An application cannot be added as a `Owner` of another application. It is limited to only users.

[image]

For managing one app with another , you can use only ***graph api permissions*** like you have already mentioned `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`.

You can also add **custom app roles** to your application which can be assigned to `users/groups` and `applications` as well while token generation.

You can refer this **[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)** for more information.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` is an Application permission, not a Delegated permission. How would that work if the Application cannot be an owner of another Application? Even the description of the permission says so; `Manage apps that this app creates or owns`